# numpy broadcasting and conditionals

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, broadcast

I'm shure the question is already asked somewhere, but i dont have the right keywords to find a solution...

my problem is to ameliorate the following code :

```
I = np.array([True,False])
x = np.array([1,2])
result = f(x) * (1 - I) + g(x) * I
```

Where in fact, `I` is used as a conditional : do the first thing if I is True, else do the second one. `f` and `g` are suppose to be (2,) -> (2,) functions.

Is there a way that i could write this such that the 2 functions `f` and `g` are computed only when needed, and not everywhere ? Here i have 2 values, but in application i have hundreds and thoose functions are costly.

Comment: Use numpy.where: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: If i understood corretly the docutmentation, numpy.where does not avoid computation of g(x) if not needed : it computes everything and then chooses. So that's nto what i need...

Comment: What do you mean by `g` and `f` are `(2,)` to `(2,)`? If I understand you correctly you want each of them to process only one input in the example, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.piecewise` is probably what you want. For example:

```
I = np.array([True,False])
x = np.array([1,2])
f,g = np.square,np.negative
np.piecewise(x, I, [g,f])
# array([-1,  4])
```

One potential gotcha: The output of `np.piecewise` has the same type as `x`; so if `x` is `int` but produces `float` values these are truncated. To avoid this cast `X` to `float` or whatever is appropriate.